# Attempting to read stdout from spawned QProcess

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qprocess

I've written a Qt application to create a UI to a backend Linux console application. Now, I want the console output and the standard error to be displayed in a window in my application.

I've tried the following code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess *console_backend = new QProcess(this);
    QString file = "/path/to/console_executable";
    console_backend->start(file);

    console_backend->setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);

    QObject::connect(console_backend, SIGNAL(console_backend
                     ->readyReadStandardOutput()),
                     this, SLOT(this->receiveConsoleBackendOutput()));

}

void MainWindow::receiveConsoleBackendOutput()
{
    //..celebrate !
}
```

When I execute the application, the error that I get is :

```
Object::connect: No such signal
QProcess::console_backend>readyReadStandardOutput() in
../projekt_directory/mainwindow.cpp:239 
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
```

Am I understanding signals-and-slots wrong ? Why is it "No such signal" ? 
Is the entire approach wrong ?

Comment: You do. `connect(console_backend, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(receiveConsoleBackendOutput()));`

Comment: @Amartel    Oh shit. That's the real code copy-pasted. Its supposed to be console_backend in place of real_code. Your suggestion works to remove the error.

Comment: `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` are macros, which convert methods' names into strings, so you need to remove all `this->` etc. calls. Just methods' signatures. Read Qt's manual for more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is in statement

```
QObject::connect(console_backend, SIGNAL(console_backend
                 ->readyReadStandardOutput()),
                 this, SLOT(this->receiveConsoleBackendOutput()));
```

It should be

```
QObject::connect(console_backend, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),
                 this, SLOT(receiveConsoleBackendOutput()));
```